# Unrecognized Selector Sent to instance while adding a subview

Tags: xcode4.2

I am getting this thread while running my app.

```
2012-07-10 15:44:39.668 DSSAmple[447:f803] -[cell superview]: unrecognized selector sent       to instance 0x68b4080
2012-07-10 15:44:39.671 DSSAmple[447:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[cell superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68b4080'
```

'cell' is called my subclass.

In cell.h i have

```
@interface cell : UIViewController
{
UIImage *MyImage;
int row;
int column;
CGRect frame;
}
@property(retain,nonatomic)UIImage *MyImage;
@property(assign,nonatomic)int row;
@property(assign,nonatomic)CGRect frame;
@property(assign,nonatomic)int column;
@end
```

And in my calling class i have
  SIAViewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cell.h"
@interface SIAViewController : UIViewController
-(void)PanelLoading;
@end
```

In its implementation
 SIAViewController.m

```
-(void)PanelLoading
{
UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"s.jpg"];
int x=20,y=50,r=1,c=1;
for (int i=1; i<=8; i++) 
{
    for (int j=1; j<=8; j++) 

    {
        cell *tank=[[cell alloc]init];
        tank.column=c;
        tank.row=r;
        tank.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 35, 35);
        tank.MyImage=myImage;
        [self.view addSubview:tank];
        x+=35;
        r++;
    }
    r=1;
    c++;
    y+=35;
    x=20;
}

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self PanelLoading];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

What Would be the reason for this? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Your `cell` class should extend `UIView` rather than `UIViewController`.

```
@interface cell : UIView
```

`UIView` provides a `superview` property, while `UIViewController` does not, triggering the "unrecognized selector" crash.

Comment: Ok. ThankYou very much. i understand that.But still its not displaying anything

Comment: @Deepak This is a separate issue. My guess would be that this is because your `cell` is not drawing itself on its superview. Did you override `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`? I am not even sure that your `cell` is designed optimally: could you use `UIImageView` instead of a custom `cell` view?